# Activity opening itself when calling startActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `MainActivity` in this activity I got a fragment, which has a listView. When clicking on an item in this listView I do this:

`startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),` CategoryActivity.class));

this works fine as it starts my `CategoryActivity.class` **but** it first starts the `MainActivity` again and only after that it is opening my `CategoryActivity`. I don't understand why this is happening. So now when I press the backbutton in my `CategoryActivity` I get to my `MainActivity` and I can press the backbutton again and again come back to `MainActivity`.

Any thoughts on why this could happen?

**Edit: My onclick code**

```
storeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {

         // some irrelevant code

         final View v = view;

         final IQueryResult<IStoreItemConfiguration> itemConfigs = new IQueryResult<IStoreItemConfiguration>() {
             @Override
             public void result(List<IStoreItemConfiguration> results) {

                 // some code

                 startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), CategoryActivity.class));
             }
         }
    }
}
```

**Edit: relevant part of my manifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_category"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Comment: post your code that handles onclick of item

Comment: @KaranMer please see my edit

Comment: It looks fine, make sure you are not starting `MainActivity` when you press back in nextactivity. post your on backpressed code in nextactivity

Comment: Please show your AndroidManifest.xml as well

Comment: @KaranMer no I don't. I also see that mainactivity is opening again before it opens my next activity.

Comment: make sure you are not calling any other method in onitemclick that might be starting your activity again.

Comment: @Christopher please see my edit.
KaranMer Thanks. I did. I am not calling it.

Comment: where is the MyNextActivity in Manifest ??

Comment: @AalapPatel sorry it is called `CategoryActivity` like in my code example below. I will edit the first example in my question.

Comment: yes so I see it has parent activity as MainAvticity thats why on clicking back you go to main avtivity from category activity, try taking parent activity out from that and see.

Comment: @AalapPatel I want it to go back to mainactivity when clicking 'back'

Comment: It seems like addin `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to my `MainActivity` fixed the issue.

Comment: Why are you taking the context from the view and not from the activity itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CategoryActivity.class));
```

in `onBackPressed()` put `finish()` or `finishAffinity()`, like however you want.

Comment: The problem already occurs on starting the Activity. I already do what you are suggesting for starting it.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Intent intent = new Intent(listView.getContext(),/*Your next activity*/);
listView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Best way of calling `Activity` from `Fragment` class is that make `interface` in Fragment and add `onItemClick()` method in that interface. Now implement it to your first activity and call second activity from there.

If you want to call from your fragment, you can use this method.

```
public class **YourFragmentClass** extends Fragment {

    Context context; //Declare the variable context

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Pass your layout xml to the inflater and assign it to rootView.
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.**yourfragmentxml**, container, false); 
            context = rootView.getContext(); // Assign your rootView to context

            Button **yourButton** = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.**your_button_id**);
            **yourButton**.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Pass the context and the Activity class you need to open from the Fragment Class, to the Intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, **YourActivityClass**.class); 
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the only difference is here, that you are using `rootView.getContext()` when I am doing this the same problem occurs.

Comment: If you have tried using `getActivity()` and `getContext()` then u can go with the best method as I suggested that u must use an interface.

Comment: I don't see why this would fix the problem and why it shouldn't work like I do it now.

Comment: See, why it should work and why it shouldn't- the answer to these can be then found out but one need to try the suggested answer first. Then u can ask why this worked and this didn't

Comment: The thing is that I use the same code as shown in other activities and there it works for me and I don't want to change this code structure like this when I don't even see a reason why this could help.